# How to prove that the eigenvalue(s) appears on the diagonal matrix $D=[T]_\beta$ are all the eigenvalue(s) of $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$ that is diagonalizable with basis $\beta$, how to prove that the eigenvalue(s) appears on the diagonal matrix $D=[T]_\beta$ are all the eigenvalue(s) of $T$? I haven't come up with any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues of $T$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial of its matrix with respect to some basis, in particular with respect to $\beta$. But that matrix is $D$ and its eigenvalues are the entries of the main diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

The $i$-th column vector of $[T]_{\beta}$  is $[T (b_i)]_{\beta}$, where $b_i$ is the $i$-th basis vector in $\beta$ (basis consisting of eigenvectors). Now $Tb_i=\lambda_i b_i$, so the column has $\lambda_i$ in the ith place and zeroes elsewhere.
Starting with such a representation similarly one would show that these diagonal entries must correspond to eigenvalues.

Comment: For $Tb_i$ did you meant $T(b_i)$? And I still don't know is why those $\lambda_i$ are all the eigenvalue(s) of $T$, so there is no other eigenvalue(s), which may not on the diagonal. Sorry I didn't make it clear...

Comment: @Isana Yashiro Yes that is what I mean. If $T $ is defined on $\mathbb {R} $, and diagonisable, then it has $n $ linearly independent eigenvectors (and $D $ is $n\times n $) . The corresponding eigenvalues must appear on the diagonal (according to their geometric multeplicity), and as we said above. There can be no other eigenvalues (all the $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors are elements of the basis $\beta $,  no fewer will do, and we can't have more.